# How to filter an array by items from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

We are creating an application using vue and vuex. We have an array of venue id's for venues that a user is following. We want each user to see a list of the all of TITLES of venues they are following.

For example:

```
venues: [
{venue:1, title: Shoreline}
{venue:2, title: Bill Graham}
{venue:3, title: Golden Gate}
{venue:4, title: Orphium}
]
```

I'm following: [1, 3]

But I don't want to show results 1 and 3. I want the results on the page to show that I'm following "Shoreline" and "Golden Gate"

I've been trying to use map and filter functions but can't get it to work.

```
getFollowingState({ commit, state }) {
  fb.venueFollowersCollection.where("user", "==", state.currentUser.uid).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    let followingArray = []
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
      let followed = doc.data().venue
      followingArray.push(followed)
    })
    store.dispatch('getUserVenues', followingArray)
    commit('setFollowedVenues', followingArray)
  })
},
```

This gives me an array of all of the ids for the venues that I am following. Here is what doc.data() looks like:

```
email: "greg@..."
name: "Gre..."
phone: "925..."
user: "jxckuJwXxRdgfKmEduYlLbfxd1g1"
venue: "S2XWn8tG0tIMyoOyAcuc"
venueName: "California Memorial Stadium"
```

Next, I want to get each venue object where the id is in the array of ids of venues I'm following (payload).

```
getUserVenues({ commit }, payload) {
  fb.venuesCollection.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    let venuesArray = []
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {        
      if ((doc.data()).includes(payload)) {
        let venue = doc.data()
        venuesArray.push(venue)
        console.log(doc.data())
      }
    })
    console.log(venuesArray)
    commit("setUserVenues", venuesArray)
  })
},
```

This part doesn't work because "payload" isn't a string. What do I need to be doing differently?

Comment: What does `doc.data()` look like? It's helpful to know the structure of the thing you are traversing. And `payload` is an array of id strings?

Comment: David, I updated the question to include the console.log for doc.data()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to filter array by items from another array is to use includes() fucntion:

```
const venues = [
{venue:1, title: 'Shoreline'},
{venue:2, title: 'Bill Graham'},
{venue:3, title: 'Golden Gate'},
{venue:4, title: 'Orphium'}
];

const following = [1, 3];

const tittles = venues
  .filter(item => following.includes(item.venue))
  .map(item => item.title);

console.log(tittles);
```

Out:

> [ 'Shoreline', 'Golden Gate' ]

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you want is something like this:

```js
getUserVenues({ commit }, payload) {
  fb.venuesCollection.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    const venuesArray = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const venue = doc.data();
      if (payload.includes(venue.venue)) {
        venuesArray.push(venue);
      }
    });
    commit('setUserVenues', venuesArray);
  });
},
```

The variables are a bit confusing because your `venue` object has a `venue` field, instead of an `id` (at least that's how I interpret your question). So if `venue.venue` is the id you want to match in `payload`, then `payload.includes` is what you needed.

If you want to commit something other than the whole venue object you could do something like:

**commit just the names**

```js
commit('setUserVenues', venuesArray.map(v => v.venueName));
```

**commit just the names and ids**

```js
commit('setUserVenues', venuesArray.map(v => ({ id: v.venue, title: v.venueName})));
```